# How to simplify compounded division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you simplify something like: 
$$(1184 / 60) / 60$$
How do you figure out what to divide the number by just once to come out the same as when you divide it twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(a/b)/c=a/(bc)$.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perfect, thanks. what do you call this procedure? if anything.

Comment: I call it "understanding how division works," but I don't think it has any snappy official-sounding name.

Comment: lol long day. Normally i would think about it but i've been meaning to start participating on here anyhow.

Comment: @Marshall: You could call it "multiplying numerator and denominator by $b$" as in $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}=\frac{b\times\frac{a}{b}}{b\times c} =\frac{a}{b c}$$

Answer (score 5):

$\rm Hint\!:\ (A/B)/C\ = X$

$\rm\ \ \iff\  A/B\ =\ C\ X$

$\rm\ \ \iff\  \: A\, =\, B(C\ X)$

$\rm\ \ \iff\  \: A\, = (BC)\:\! X\ $ by multiplication is **associative**

$\rm\ \ \iff\ A/(BC) = X$

Thus $\,\rm(A/B)/C = A/(BC)\,$ is a division form of the associativity of multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Sandwich: The bread goes on top, the ham and cheese in the bottom:
$$\frac{\quad\frac{a}{b}\quad{\leftarrow\text{bread}\atop \leftarrow\text{cheese}}\quad}{\quad\frac{c}{d}\quad{\leftarrow\text{ham}\atop\leftarrow\text{bread}}\quad} = \frac{ad}{bc}\quad{\leftarrow\text{bread}\atop\leftarrow\text{ham and cheese}}
$$

You have $a=1186$, $b=60$, $c=60$, and $d=1$:
$$\frac{\quad\frac{1186}{60}\quad}{60} = \frac{\quad\frac{1186}{60}\quad}{\frac{60}{1}} = \frac{(1186)(1)}{(60)(60)}.$$

Comment: Oi va voi! Such treyf! Readers whose sensibilities are offended can substitute lox and cream cheese.

Comment: why is "d" necessary?

Comment: @Marshall: It's not *strictly* necessary, but with it, your problem fits into the general scheme of dividing a fraction by a fraction. Likewise, if you had $$\frac{a}{\quad\frac{c}{d}\quad}$$you could just try to remember that it's the same as $\frac{ad}{c}$, or you could make it fit into the general scheme of dividing a fraction by a fraction. Since dividing a fraction by a fraction shows up a lot, might as well see the general case.

Comment: Now you made me hungry.